# mysql querying from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok, I was having some trouble accomplishing this and, quite frankly, don't even know if it is possible to do what I want.

I have the following table structure:
Table Structure

```
Tags (t)
============
ID
LINE_ID
TAG
ACTIVE

Dashboard Lines (dl)
===============
ID
LINE_ID
GAUGE_TAG_ID
DISPLAY_NAME
ACTIVE

Dashboard Points (dp)
================
ID
DASHBOARD_ID
TAG_ID
DISPLAY_NAME
```

What I am trying to do is pull all of the `t.TAG` into a single result based on all of the IDs in the `'Dashboard Points'` table. The one exception is the `GAUGE_TAG_ID in the Dashboard_Lines table`. I also need to pull that tag as well. I have been able to successfully pull all of the `t.TAG` into a single result joining on `dp.TAG_ID = t.ID`. Unfortunately I have not figured out how to also include joining on the `dl.gauge_tag_id` to get the correlating `t.tag` associated with the ID.

My current query (not pulling the gauge_tag_id)

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.TAG), dl.gauge_tag_id, dl.line_id
FROM tags t
JOIN dashboard_lines dl ON dl.line_id = t.line_id
JOIN dashboard_points dp ON dp.tag_id = t.id AND dp.dashboard_id = dl.id
WHERE t.line_id = '1'                                                       
AND t.active = 'Y'
```

This successfully groups all the `t.TAG` with correlating ids`on t.ID and dl.TAG_ID`

Is it possible to also include the `t.TAG for the dl.GAUGE_TAG_ID`?

Edit: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ace98d

Edit 2:
Desired Results:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(t.TAG)
Line1_Over_Cnt, Line1_Case_Count, Line1_MaxCap..
```

(all the correlating tag_ids along with the gauge_tag_id -- displayed as the t.TAG)

This doesn't have to be all in one column (GROUP_CONCAT). It can be a traditional result set with all of the `t.TAG` so long as it includes all of them (the dp.TAG_ID on t.ID) and (dl.GAUGE_TAG_ID on t.ID)

```
TAG
Line1_Over_Cnt
Line1_Case_Count
Line1_MaxCap
Line1_Idle
Kleins_Line1_Reset
L1_STD_Rate
Line1_Rate_Temp
Line1_Rate
```

Edit3: Possible Solution

```
SELECT t1.tag
FROM tags t1
JOIN dashboard_lines dl ON dl.line_id = t1.line_id
JOIN dashboard_points dp ON dp.tag_id = t1.id AND dp.dashboard_id = dl.id
WHERE t1.line_id = '1'                                                       
AND t1.active = 'Y'
UNION
SELECT t2.tag
FROM tags t2
JOIN dashboard_lines dl ON gauge_tag_id = t2.id AND dl.line_id = '1'
WHERE t2.line_id = '1'                                                       
AND t2.active = 'Y'
```

This gives me all the tags listed in individual rows. Is this the best way? Is there a way to get them all into a single, concatenated result?

-- End edits --

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: I've added an SQLFiddle. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: No need for a GROUP BY dl.gauge_tag_id, dl.line_id?

Comment: Was that my suggestion?

Comment: I thought I explained the desired results, but I have edited to try and be more clear. Added a multiple row result example that would suffice.

Comment: Edited with possible solution.. Feedback? Problems?

Comment: Yes - if there's no relationship between dp and dl then this is the best way - although there are lots of ways of writing it. For instance, you can UNION everything inside a subquery, and then apply the WHERE in the super query. Note that the alias t2 can be t1 - or they can both just be t

Comment: Thanks Strawberry. I will keep your suggestions (and example below) in mind for my following posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Edit3, you are almost there. Encapsulate everything in another select that can do the group concat for you.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tags) FROM 
(
  SELECT t1.tag as tags
  FROM tags t1
  JOIN dashboard_lines dl ON dl.line_id = t1.line_id
  JOIN dashboard_points dp ON dp.tag_id = t1.id AND dp.dashboard_id = dl.id
  WHERE t1.line_id = '1'                                                       
  AND t1.active = 'Y'
  UNION
  SELECT t2.tag as tags
  FROM tags t2
  JOIN dashboard_lines dl ON gauge_tag_id = t2.id AND dl.line_id = '1'
  WHERE t2.line_id = '1'                                                       
  AND t2.active = 'Y'
) A;
```

Comment: This is it! Exactly what I was trying for. Thank you!